# Style material Mat-option mat-select

Tags: css, angular-material, material-ui, angular-material2

I have following code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name.value">
     {{ name.value }}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

My name value may include several contiguous spaces, for example, 3xxx4xxxxName, where x denotes a space. Default behaviors would strip all spaces except one space. The name value will be displayed as 3x4xname. Is there a way style the name? I think I need to use

```
white-space:pre-wrap
```

However, I do not know where to put the class to make it work. Any help is welcome. After I added the scss file.

```
.mat-option {
  white-space:pre;
 }
```

The combobox stops working.

Comment: view-source:(your url) and show what's rendered that you can easily select the specific dom element

Comment: I did find .mat-option is the class. However, the combbox stops working when I added class.

Comment: It will be great if you provide a fiddle for your issue

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766597/styling-mat-select-in-angular-material