# How to set values to angular material Constants like SELECT_PANEL_MAX_HEIGHT

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

How to assign value to the Angular Material Constants like *SELECT_PANEL_MAX_HEIGHT* Which are provided in the official angular Material Documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#SELECT_PANEL_MAX_HEIGHT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants such as SELECT_PANEL_MAX_HEIGHT is read only. You can only override options which have a special Injection token. For example: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS for Material tooltip.

```
import { MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from "@angular/material";

...

providers: [
    {
        provide: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
        useValue: {
            showDelay: 500,
            hideDelay: 300
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: @masu9 if an injection token is provided you can use it to override the default behavior or values.
[Tooltip Constants](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api#constants)

Comment: Is there any way to change the value of a constant to modify the behavior of a component? For example, the animation speed of the expansion panel

Comment: @AndresGardiol take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aubesd and try to change EXPANSION_PANEL_ANIMATION_TIMING constant

Answer (score 1):

Another option to make the select panel bigger or smaller:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  max-height: 80vh !important;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52975755/399527

Comment: ::ng-deep seems to be deprecated, and it did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

see https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11780, the following worked for me:

```
.mat-select-panel {
  max-height: 300px!important;
}
```