# Angular material datepicker hide/delete disabled years

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

I have disabled years before 2018 but I want to hide/delete them.

Range for year selection is showing from 1998 it should be 2018.

Can we show only 3-4 years cause here its showing 24 years.

[image]

Comment: How you have *disabled years before 2018*?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the dates available for navigation and selection using `[minDate]` and `[maxDate]` inputs. If you don't specify any of them, you will have infinite navigation and the year select box will display -10, +10 years from currently visible month.

To set `minDate` and `maxDate` *hardcoded* in HTML-template:

```
<ngb-datepicker
        [minDate]="{year: 2018, month: 1, day: 1}"
        [maxDate]="{year: 2024, month: 12, day: 31}">
</ngb-datepicker>
```

If you want set the `minDate` and `maxDate` *dynamically*, you can set the dates in the *component.ts* file as follow:

```
now: Date = new Date();

minDate: any;
maxDate: any;

this.minDate = { year: this.now.getFullYear() - 3, month: this.now.getMonth() + 1, day: this.now.getDate() };

this.maxDate = { year: this.now.getFullYear() + 2, month: this.now.getMonth() + 1, day: this.now.getDate() };
```

This will give you a date-range from todays date -3 years, until todays date and +2 years.

In the HTML-template you would then have to reference to the ’minDate`and`maxDate`:

```
<ngb-datepicker
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate">
</ngb-datepicker>
```

Comment: Actually I did using same way that's why in image years before 2018 are disabled but I want to hide/delete those years. I need to show only 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 in date picker.

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant in material that controls it. [yearsPerPage](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#yearsPerPage). Not sure if/how one can change it, though.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54918627/7172671), you can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in this and don't mind the limited browser support, you can use :has() selector to hide the td's that have a child button which is disabled.
Here is how I solved it:

Add style overrides:

```
::ng-deep {
  // This hides disabled calendar cells so only the clickable ones are visible
  // Note: this will hide any cell inside material angular datepicker, including year, month and day cells
  td.mat-calendar-body-cell-container:has(> button.mat-calendar-body-disabled) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Add min and max to the datepicker that you are using (date-range in my case)

```
<mat-date-range-input [min]="startOfReport" [max]="today">...
```

Result: [image]